# Merging two columns at once in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 127 columns and 518 rows. Now I have to odd and even columns (from 3).

```
>data
Name id S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6
abc  1  A  A  C  C  G  G
abc  2  A  G  T  T  C  G
abc  3  G  C  T  A  A  C
```

The output which I want is

```
>output
Name id S2 S4 S6  
abc  1  AA  CC  GG
abc  2  AG  TT  CG
abc  3  GC  TA  AC
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please don't share value of data.frame like you have shown in the question description. Always share output of `dput(head(data.frame))` so that it becomes easy for other to quickly work on the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Ill follow this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map` to do this after subsetting the alternate columns

```
res <- data.frame(data[1:2], Map(paste0, data[-(1:2)][c(TRUE, FALSE)], 
                  data[-(1:2)][c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
names(res)[3:5] <-  names(data)[3:8][c(FALSE, TRUE)]
res
#   Name id S2 S4 S6
#1  abc  1 AA CC GG
#2  abc  2 AG TT CG
#3  abc  3 GC TA AC
```